# how can i use styled-component and local font in next js?

Tags: next.js

i am using styled-component in my next js app.

and for using it i had to add a babel file with this code:

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

i want to use local font and i did it according to the document https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization.
but problem is here that after using local font the app errors.
it errors that you have to use initial babel.
how can i use both styled-component and local font?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Next.js 12 you can use styled-components without additional plugins.

Just add `styledComponents: true` in your next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...rest of your config,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

[A related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30802)